# Fabric-Mopub/Android Single Native ad In Activity

Tags: android, native, mopub

I'm an Android Developper and I use Mopub/Fabric to integrate ads in my apps.
For Banner/Interstitiel/Native Ad List, it's ok.
But I have some issues with a specific way to integrate Native Ad.
Let me explain  : I have an Activity (with a ViewPager) which implement an Adapter (BaseAdapter) and a ViewHolder to display data. In each child of my ViewPager, there are :

- First : Some text
- Second : My Native Ad
- Third : A button.

Is there a way to accomplish this with a MoPubAdAdapter or something else ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is referenced from the MoPub Forums [here](https://twittercommunity.com/t/single-native-ad-in-activity/44751).

You can use MoPubAdAdapter to wrap your ViewPager to display native ads.

It's recommend having each Native Ad fill its own ViewHolder. By defining the XML layout of the ad, you can have the ad's text image and CTA button display in the format you want in your image.

Please see our documentation on integrating native ads [here](https://github.com/mopub/mopub-android-sdk/wiki/Native-Ads-Integration) for information on how to set up this layout.

If you want to display an entire native ad within the ViewHolder, this may be more difficult and may require a custom integration.